# How do i set ghost theme routes.yaml filter?

Tags: ghost-blog, hbs

I want to apply multiple filters.

However, because of the preceding code, the code below seems to have no data to filter.

for example,

```
routes:

collections:
  /tag/blog/en/:
    permalink: /{slug}/en/
    template: index
    filter: "tag:hash-en+tag:blog"
  /tag/sns/en/:
    permalink: /{slug}/en/
    template: index
    filter: "tag:hash-en+tag:sns"
  /:
    permalink: /{slug}/
    template: index
    filter: "tag:hash-en"
```

in this case if i link to `/` main page,
i want to see all of `en` tag posts,
Due to the tag filter of blog and sns, the hash-en at the bottom seems to have no data to filter.
how can i fix it?